# Dynamic navigation in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, navigation

I have a site with a layout that doesn't really change much, but the content within the layout changes. I can't find a really good way to do this in ember. Here is basically what I have so far:

#### templates/application.hbs

```
<header>
  <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
</header>
<nav>
  {{link-to 'Home' 'index'}}
  {{link-to 'About' 'about'}}
</nav>
<main>
  {{outlet}}
</main>
```

#### app.js

```
/* Other app stuff... */

Ember.Route.reopen({
  defaultTitle: Ember.computed('routeName', function() {
    return this.get('routeName')
      .camelize()
      .capitalize()
      .replace(/\./g, ' - ')
      .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
  }),
  activate() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.updateTitle();
  },
  updateTitle: Ember.observer('title', function() {
    let title = this.get('title') || this.get('defaultTitle');
    this.controllerFor('application').set('title', title);
  }
});
```

This seems to work alright. If I want to override a title I can just add `title: 'Much better name than the default'` to the route.

However, it feels like an anti-pattern. Let's say I want to add a subtitle to certain routes, based on the model. First off, I would modify the template:

#### templates/application.hbs

```
<header>
  <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
  <span class="subtitle">{{subtitle}}</span>
</header>
<!-- the rest is the same -->
```

Then, ideally on the route or controller I could just add an alias (e.g. `subtitle: Ember.computed.alias('model.location')`), but instead I have to create a new hook and manually set the new value when the model changes. This all just seems really clunky:

#### routes/about.js

```
afterModel(model) {
  this.set('subtitle', model.get('location'));
}
```

#### app.js

```
activate() {
  /* same as before */
  this.updateSubtitle();
},
updateSubtitle: Ember.observer('subtitle', function() {
  this.controllerFor('application').set('subtitle', this.get('subtitle'));
}
```

It seems like `application.hbs` is the right place to put basic layout, but it feels like I'm doing something wrong. Updating the title should be simpler. I would imagine I could just do something like `{{currentRoute.title}}`.

If I want to update the nav links dynamically, I'd run into a similar issue. It seems like I should just be able to do something like:

#### templates/application.js

```
<nav>
  {{#each router.routes as |route|}}
    {{link-to route.title route.href}}
    {{#if route.isActive}}
      {{#each route.subroutes as |subroute|}}
        {{link-to subroute.title subroute.href class="subroute"}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</nav>
```

Is there some kind of best-practice for dealing with dynamic navigation like this? In Aurelia, you can pretty easily do something like `${router.currentInstruction.config.title}` or

```
<a repeat.for="route of router.navigation"
   href.bind="route.href"
   class="${route.isActive ? 'is-active' : ''}"
>${route.title}</a>
```

I haven't found anything like that with Ember, but it seems like it should be a relatively common paradigm.

Comment: [ember addons to the rescue](https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-document-title)

Comment: Hmm, looks interesting but I'm not really trying to set the document title (yet).

Comment: woops, I m guilty of not reading past `{{title}}` x.x

Comment: Hm, I think you basically want the [Router Service](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/router-service/text/0000-router-service.md)

Comment: @Lux that sounds nice! How can you check the status of that (e.g. if it's approved, if anyone's working on it, when it might be available, etc)?

Comment: Just check the [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/95). I think for now you have to work around, but keep in mind that this might come. For now maybe just check out `{{link-to}}` works and go with private API. Or just use a Object instead of a simple string and do as you did for now. ;-)

Comment: I might have to reword the question, but I think what'd be even better if in `templates/application.hbs` I could do something like `{{outlet "nav-links"}}`  (similar to how you can `yield` in multiple spots), or render a component that was aware of the current route's context (maybe something like `{{my-nav-component context=currentRoute}}`. Not really sure what the best option is right now. So far I'm just expanding my hacked together example.

Comment: @redbmk sounds like classic use case for [ember-elsewhere](https://github.com/ef4/ember-elsewhere) or [ember-wormhole](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-wormhole).

Comment: That looks promising! I'll have to see what I can come up with. I love how ember has a plugin for everything